# Contact Form 7: Make field required after checkbox is checked

Tags: filters, validation, plugin-contact-form-7

I have a telephone field in Contact Form 7 as follows:

```
[tel Phone id:Phone]
```

and a checkbox that for users to optionally choose to be called back:

```
[checkbox Callback id:Callback "Rückruf gewünscht"]
```

The tel field should become obligatory once a user ticks the Callback checkbox. 
I followed the short tutorial and the checkbox modification from the comments from [here](https://second-cup-of-coffee.com/conditional-required-contact-form-7-fields/) and then have the following code to custom validate the tel field:

```
// CF7: Conditional required field

add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_tel', 'xxx_conditional_required', 9, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_tel*', 'xxx_conditional_required', 9, 2 );

function xxx_conditional_required($result, $tag) {
    $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );

    $name = $tag['name'];

    $value = isset( $_POST[$name] )
        ? trim( wp_unslash( strtr( (string) $_POST[$name], "\n", " " ) ) )
        : '';

    if ( 'Phone' == $name && 'Rückruf gewünscht' ==  $_POST['Callback'][0] ) :
        if ( '' == $value  ) :
            $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) );
        endif;
    endif;

    return $result;
}
```

While it (in)validates the tel field successfully once the checkbox is checked, the validation loops forever when the checkbox has **not** been checked, no matter if the tel field has been filled out at all. Am I missing something in the process?

Comment: Check out this link: https://second-cup-of-coffee.com/conditional-required-contact-form-7-fields/